# Upgrading from Angular 2.2.3 to 2.4.0

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I've just upgraded my Angular project from Angular 2.2.3 to 2.4.0 using [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates).  Upon compilation using angular-cli, I am receiving this warning.  The application itself seems to run fine, though.

```
>ng build
--snip--
ERROR in AppModule is not an NgModule
```

The problem is that it is not giving me any information on what the issue could possibly be.  If any other code or information is needed, I can provide that.

**New package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.0",
    "bootswatch": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.4",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
```

**Old package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.3",
    "bootswatch": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.1",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { routes } from './app.router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BoardIndexComponent } from './board-index/board-index.component';
import { ViewForumComponent } from './view-forum/view-forum.component';
import { ViewTopicComponent } from './view-topic/view-topic.component';
import { PostingComponent } from './posting/posting.component';

import { DatabaseService } from './services/database.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ // Components and directives 
    AppComponent,
    BoardIndexComponent,
    ViewForumComponent,
    ViewTopicComponent,
    PostingComponent
  ],
  imports: [ // Module dependencies
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routes
  ],
  providers: [DatabaseService], // Services
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] // Root component
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Make sure you've updated your angular-cli version to beta 24 (global & local)

Comment: This issue persists using angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.24, both local and global.

Comment: I suggest you just run `ng init` and then press d to `diff` to check what's difference and implement the difference, I did myself and I works for me. and also have a look at this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3157

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your package.json file similar to this

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.2",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.41",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.34",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.38",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.7.0",
    "karma": "1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.4.0",
    "protractor": "4.0.14",
    "ts-node": "1.7.2",
    "tslint": "4.2.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.10"
  }
```

and run "npm install" once again.Even more better if you clean node_modules folder before that. After that run "npm -g angular-cli@latest". More over 
in angular-cli.json file property "assets" should now be array instead of scalar:
"assets": ["assets"] and defaults section should now be added :

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": true,
      "template": true
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
```

Something like this:

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "name": "testcli"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": ["assets"],
      "index": "indexcli.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [],
      "scripts": [
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": true,
      "template": true
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

After all these preparations - ng build should work ...

Comment: You don't need to do all this things, only downgrade the typescript as @oidualc said is his answer.

Comment: Only in angular 2.4,1 they resolved the problem with aot compiling

Comment: And better to use 2.4.2 where everything works smoothly even with typescript 2.1.4

Comment: is there a reference somewhere that shows what versions go with what. ie: what version of router goes with angular 2.1.1 etc etc. asking cause some of my plugins dont work with newer versions of angular so need to downgrade

Comment: Yes there is: "ng --version" in command line shows such kind of information (of course if angular-cli installed). But you should do this inside of angular-cli project directory

Answer (score 4):

It's about some breaking change with Typescript 2.1.x, just downgrading to 2.0.x fixes the problem for now (until a fix is published upstream).

Comment: Yup:
    "typescript": "2.0.x"
in package.json cured it for me.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, TypeScript 2.1 is not supported at the moment.

If you are using Angular CLI, the right way to upgrade your project is as follows:

```
npm uninstall --global angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install --global angular-cli
ng init
```

This will offer to override many files. Since you should be using git anyway, you are encouraged to let it override `angular-cli.json` and `package.json` and other framework specific files (`src/test.ts` and `src/tsconfig.json` etc if asked to override. But you don't need to override `app/` files for example).

Once it's finished, review the diff in git and restore any NPM packages or scripts it might have removed.

Then delete node_modules, and run `npm install`.